# Satzzeichen: "vielen Dank für Ihre Nachricht!" oder "vielen Dank für Ihre Nachricht."

Tags: punctuation

> Sehr geehrter Herr Müller,
>
> *herzlichen Dank für Ihre freundliche Einladung*
>
> ...
>
> *vielen Dank für Ihre Nachricht*
>
> ...
>
> *vielen Dank für die Rückmeldung*

Gelten die oben genannten Sätze als Ausrufesätze? Setzt man am Satzende ein Ausrufezeichen oder einen Punkt?

Answer (score 3):

Wenn es formell ist und z.B. für eine Bewerbung benutzt wird, würde ich soweit es geht auf Ausrufezeichen **verzichten** und einfach ein Punkt oder ein Komma setzen (je nachdem, ob der Satz fortgeführt wird...):

> Vielen Dank für die Rückmeldung.

Bei einem *Ausrufesatz* werden meistens Gefühle ausgedrückt, dies können Gefühle wie Erstaunen, Abneigung, Freude oder Aufregung sein.

#### Beispiele:

> "Ach, endlich kommt die Post!"

> "Wie teuer ist das nur geworden!"

> "Ich war vielleicht aufgeregt!"

---

Bei deinen drei Beispielsätze wird jedoch meiner Meinung nach nichts über Gefühle geschrieben, sondern für verschiedene Dinge bedankt. Somit sind das für mich keine Ausrufesätze und es gehört **kein** Ausrufezeiche sondern ein **Punkt** oder ein **Komma** hin.

Answer (score 2):

Nein, das sind grammatisch keine Ausrufesätze - eigentlich sind es ja gar keine vollständigen Sätze, sondern Dankesformeln. Man setzt normalerweise einen Punkt,  man kann aber, wenn der Text nicht sehr formell ist, zur Verstärkung oder besonderen Betonung des Dankes auch ein Ausrufezeichen setzen. Das wird relativ häufig so gemacht.

Zu viele Ausrufezeichen in einem Text sollte man nicht verwenden, der Effekt nutzt sich schnell ab, und es wirkt dann schnell übertrieben.